# ViewComponent With CRUD Operations in ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have a list with multiple list item, when i fill list header's properties then i'm allowed to add list item.

- List Item need to have CRUD functionality.
- List must be a grid
- Adding to List must with creating new record and fill it instantly

I'm very novice to ASP.Net Core MVC, i read some articles about ViewComponent to accomplish that but i'm not convinced that it can be a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> List Item need to have CRUD functionality
>
> List must be a grid
>
> Adding to List must with creating new record and fill it instantly

So write logic in action of `ViewComponent` (for example with `if` statement based on parameters passed to action). I dont understand where is a problem in this basic things. If you are new into ASP.NET Core i can reccomend read [official docs about view components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) but better start from [.Net Core basic tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/) (and some C# tutorials...)